# Bash scripting rsync: rsync: link_stat (blah) failed: No such file or directory (2)

Tags: bash, scripting, rsync

I am trying to write a simple bash script for my local (Mac OS X) machine to move files from a directory on my machine to a remote machine. This line is failing:

```
rsync --verbose  --progress --stats --compress --rsh=ssh \
      --recursive --times --perms --links --delete \
      --exclude "*bak" --exclude "*~" \
      /repository/* $DEV_SERVER:$REMOTE_DIR
```

`$DEV_SERVER` and `$REMOTE_DIR` are defined previously, and I echo them to verify they're accurate.

The error I'm getting is:

```
rsync: link_stat /Users/myusername/mycurrentdirectory failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

To note here is that rather than using the defined directory (`/repository`, which is in the root of the machine), it uses my working directory. What is causing this?

Comment: Quote your variables, please!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Check that your `\` characters have no whitespace after them at the end of the line. This will cause BASH to not interpret the line wrap correctly, giving the rsync error above.

Comment: In my case, this error occured when the rsync -e option was supplied with an empty string or a space char AND the target file (to be synced with) did not already exist. (The -e option value was being determined conditionally).

Answer (score 13):

Remove the '*' from the source location, rsync knows to look in the inside of the directory if you specify the '/' in the end

like that:

```
rsync --verbose  --progress --stats --compress --rsh=ssh --recursive --times --perms --links --delete --exclude "*bak" --exclude "*~" /repository/ $DEV_SERVER:$REMOTE_DIR
```

Answer (score 3):

I was encountering the same error while doing some rsync work.  I had the wrong character for specifying options which I must have gotten from copying and pasting the command from elsewhere:

```
−
```

rather than the correct character below:

```
-
```

Comment: thanks, that was a subtle one! Ran into exactly this when copy-pasting rsync arguments from various websites.

Answer (score 0):

The source path (here: `/repository/*`) does contain a wildcard (`*`).
There is some info in the man pages for rsync:
"Note  that  the expansion of wildcards on the commandline (`*.c`) into a list of files is handled by the shell before it runs  rsync  and not  by  rsync  itself (exactly the same as all other posix-style programs)."

I.e. in case you put in bash double quotes `""` around the (source path) including the wildcard symbol (`*`), the rsync commandwill succeed on command line interface, while inside a bash shell it will yield exactly the error described here.

`rsync: link_stat "<source path>*" failed: No such file or directory (2)`

=> make sure to not put the wild card(s) in quotes in an rsync source path.

Comment: I have `"rsync -r --exclude {'*.root','*tmp/','*.mac','SomeString*'} ~/mypath"` - I've tried swapping the single and double quotes but it gives me this error for `//*tmp`, `*.mac` and `BhabhaSCh*` in both cases. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Beth,
First, I do miss the <sourcepattern>  in your command sample, and assume an * is missing.
Second, there may be an equal sign '=' required for --exclude={ 'pattern1', 'pattern2', ..., 'patternN' }.
Then ultimately bash will quasi "remove" the quotes, single or double, which is why the exclude list will not work as expected (even if you add the equal sign '=').

Still, you can use --exclude multiple times without single quotes:
"rsync -r --exclude *.root --exclude *tmp/ --exclude *.mac --exclude SomeString* <sourcepattern> ~/mypath"
This should work.

Comment: You're right about the `sourcepath` - in my command I have it, but I didn't copy it here. Anyway, this still isn't working: `rsync -r --exclude *.root --exclude *tmp/ --exclude *.mac --exclude SomeString* ~/mydir/ /targetpath`, all the files I wanted to exclude are still being copied...

Comment: Beth, you are right and obviously the single quotes are necessary for --exclude. 
In order to reproduce your issue, I just created a bash script and to my surprise the single quotes do work there. the script executes just as expected, excluding files and directories which were identified with a pattern containing an asterisk.
just as a side note  - I always use the -a instead of r - but this should not be the root cause for the difference. 
Here's the script I executed:
#!/bin/sh
rsync -a --exclude '*.txt' --exclude '*xxx/' * ~/tmp

Comment: This now excludes `*.root` and `*.mac` files but not `SomeString*` files or everything that ends in `*~` which I requested it to do

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
rsync --verbose  --progress --stats --compress --rsh=ssh \
  --recursive --times --perms --links --delete \
  --exclude "*bak" --exclude "*~" \
  /repository/* $DEV_SERVER:$REMOTE_DIR
```

should be this:

```
rsync --verbose  --progress --stats --compress --rsh=ssh --recursive --times --perms --links --delete --exclude "*bak" --exclude "*~" /repository/* $DEV_SERVER:$REMOTE_DIR
```

Bash interprets the `\` character differently than the command line, or perhaps there is an implicit non-whitespace character after it.

Comment: How does bash handle it differently in non-interactive sessions?

Comment: Better suited for superuser.com

Comment: The only problem I've had with using the line-continuation-char (i.e. `\`), on cmd-line OR in a script, is when there is any character besides a `\n` character after it. I didn't downvote your answer, but I don't think it's right. Good luck to all.

Comment: This is plain wrong. Bash interprets a script exactly the same way as it interprets input from the command prompt.

Comment: There's not difference in the syntax  for interactive and non-interactive shell.